# Terminal command to record audio through macbook microphone?

Tags: macos, terminal, high-sierra, microphone

Is there a command we can use via terminal to start recording audio through my macbook microphone?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Use [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/).

(This has become one of my favorite command line utilities for video/audio conversion and streaming).  It's an open source framework for audio/video encoding, decoding, streaming, converting, and muxing.  It's included with many (paid) AV utilities.

You can capture the audio as a stream through Apple's AVFoundation.

#### Get the device ID

```
$ ffmpeg -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ""

[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fda1bc152c0] AVFoundation video devices:
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fda1bc152c0] [0] FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fda1bc152c0] [1] Capture screen 0
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fda1bc152c0] AVFoundation audio devices:
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fda1bc152c0] [0] USB Audio CODEC
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fda1bc152c0] [1] Built-in Microphone
```

The device you're going to need is ":1"  AVFoundation uses the convention "V:A" for "Video:Audio"  so, if you want to capture video from your FaceTime camera the the audio from your Microphone, you would use "0:1".  If you wanted just the audio only, you would use ":1" and leave the video out.

#### Record the Audio:

```
$ ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i ":1" -t 10 audiocapture.mp3
```

The above command will record 10 seconds of audio from the built in microphone and save it as `audiocapture.mp3`.  You can set how long you want FFMPEG to record by changing the value for `-t`.  If you want to record a full hour, set it to "3600".

```
$ ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i ":1" -t 3600 audiocapture.mp3
```

#### What the flags mean

- `-f` = "force format".  In this case we're forcing the use of AVFoundation
- `-i` = input source.  Typically it's a file, but you can use devices.

  - `"0:1"` = Record both audio and video from FaceTime camera and built-in mic
  - `"0"` = Record just video from FaceTime camera
  - `":1"` = Record just audio from built-in mic
- `-t` = time in seconds.  If you want it to run indefinitely until you stop it (<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>) omit this value (not recommended)

#### Input Volume

Keep in mind that you're using the built-in microphone which isn't great to begin with.  Ensure that you set the gain high enough (System Preferences, Sounds) so that the Mic can hear you.  It would probably be best to get a quality USB microphone instead.

Comment: This works great, thank you. What exactly is the `-f`, `-i` and `-t` here? What do they stand for? t = time? -i = input? -f = ??

Comment: Would it be possible to pipe the ffmpeg output into another command like SSH? `ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i ":1" -t 10 | ssh user@host -`. This doesn't work, ffmpeg complains "At least one output file must be specified"

Comment: It's not conducive to [pipe the output to an SSH "stream"](https://superuser.com/questions/839955/piping-output-from-ffmpeg-avconv-over-ssh-to-a-file).  You can have `ffmpeg` stream to multiple outputs including a file and a stream (like streaming music) .  See:  https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs

Comment: Yikes. All the info on codecs and filtering is a little over my head. If I create a new question here, would you try to answer it?

Comment: I'll give it my best shot...  I might not get to it right away..I am just responding to things at the moment..

Comment: okay, that's understandable. thanks. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/326419/how-to-stream-audio-using-ffmpeg

Comment: Anyway to assign this to start/stop recording using a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Yes.  There are many existing questions/answers here on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) that explain how to assign a keyboard shortcut to a script.  Answering that here would be out of scope for this question @evolutionxbox

Comment: "Is it possible" questions are usually downvoted and closed. I don't know enough to ask a coherent question.

Comment: The answer is “yes it’s possible.”  The way you ask is “how do I do this task” followed by “this is what I’ve done so far and this is where I’m stuck” to avoid being downvoted/closed.  As for your specific question - it’s [already been asked/answered](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=script+keyboard+shortcut).  That search has several relating to AppleScript and Bash and that should get you going and not get closed for being a duplicate.  The key is to try those and if you get stuck, ask a question around that part.