# How to stream audio using FFMPEG?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, audio, streaming

Building on @[Allan's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/326388/terminal-command-to-record-audio-through-macbook-microphone/326390), I'm trying to redirect the [ffmpeg output](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs) to a server.

```
$ ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i ":1" -t 10 - | ssh user@host .... -
```

But I get the following error message:

> "At least one output file must be specified"

I've also tried using [ffserver](https://organicdesign.nz/Simple_video_streaming_with_ffserver) instead of SSH but I'm not having any luck.

Is it possible to *stream* audio in this way?

Comment: Apparently it is, see https://duckduckgo.com/?q=streaming+ffmpeg+over+ssh

Answer (score 7):

There are two solutions I can visualize for this scenario:

- Saving the file to a remote computer
- Having a live stream broadcast so a remote computer can receive the audio

### Saving the file

This is probably the easiest method.  Allow the stream to finish recording then copy it to a predetermined location on the network.  This script should fit the bill:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i ":1" -t 10 audiocapture.mp3
scp audiocapture.mp3 user@host:/foo/bar/audiocapture.mp3

exit 0
```

The script doesn't do any error checking of any kind but, will record from the microphone, then when finished it will copy it via SCP (secure copy) to a remote computer.    To make this work, you need to set up [SSH Keys to facilitate a non-interactive login](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/285807/119271).

### Stream in real time

The other method, is to broadcast the audio via TCP via a point-to-point connection. Using the same input from the previous answer, we just change the output to a network stream:

```
$ ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i ":1" -t 10 -f mpegts "tcp://remote_host_or_IP_:port"
```

Where....

- `-f` is the transport format; in this case [mpegts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#mpegts) (MPEG Transport Stream)
- `tcp://remote_host_or_IP_:port` is the URI value of the remote computer's hostname/IP address and port number it will be listening on.

#### Set remote computer to "listen"

Using `ffplay` the remote computer can be set to receive the stream (I used Windows 10 for this part, but will work in macOS/Windows/BSD/Linux)

Issue the command

```
ffplay -i tcp://local_host_or_IP_addr:port?listen -hide_banner
```

Where....

- `-i` defines the input stream
- `local_host_or_IP_addr:port` is the IP address or hostname  and the TCP port of the **computer that's listening** (not the computer that's streaming).
- `?listen` is required to put it into "listen mode" otherwise it will time out if the stream is not there.

Below is an example done in Windows 10 receiving the stream from a macOS host's microphone.  The IP address of the Windows 10 machine is 10.0.0.123 and I am broadcasting on port 1234.

```
C:\Users\allan\Desktop\ffmpeg>ffplay -i tcp://10.0.0.123:1234?listen -hide_banner

    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

Once it begins to receive the broadcast, the values above will change and a player "visualization"  window will open up.

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'tcp://10.0.0.123:1234?listen':B f=0/0
384 kb/s    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
  Program 1   0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
    Metadata: 0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
Service01    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0       0B f=0/0
FFmpeg    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   sq=    0B f=0/0
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 384 kb/s
  11.35 M-A:  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

It will continue to "listen" until the process is killed.